Confused on Big-O theorem

When in Rosen's Discrete Math Textbook they give the theorem:

Suppose that $f_1(x)$ is $O(g_1(x))$ and that $f_2(x)$ is $O(g_2(x))$.
Then $(f_1 + f_2)(x)$ is $O(g(x))$, where $g(x) = (max(|g_1(x)|,\, |g_2(x)|)$ for all $x$.

What do they mean by "for all x"? Do they mean the max is 1 of the 2 g functions such that 1 of them is greater than the other g function for all possible real number inputs?

They simply mean to say that this is the definition of $g$:
$\forall x\; g(x) = \max(|g_1 (x)|, |g_2 (x)|)$

No but what would be max(x^2, x^3)?    x^3 > x^2 iff x > 1, but not all x though

For every $x$, the maximum is calculated separately. Don't let the word "all" confuse you. It means the same as "each".
In this example, $\max\left(x^{2},x^{3}\right)=\begin{cases}
x^{2} & 0<x<1\
x^{3} & 1\leq x
\end{cases}$

Wait so what would the O(max{x^2, x^3}) be then as per your understanding?

It would be a such a function $t(x)$ that satisfies the inequality: $$t(x) \le C |\max{(x^2, x^3)}|$$ where the max is evaluated separately at each $x$.
